# "out.println" not working in jsp

Tags: java, jsp

I am trying to output the following code in jsp but don't receive any output on the page. The string is contained in a `StringBuffer` object

```
<id="500000" name="XYZ" path="XYZ" parent="-1" rank="249707.0" level="1" /><id="500469" name="TAB" path="XYZ /PQR" parent="500000" rank="249275.0" level="2" />
```

Following is the piece of code I am running

```
<info>
    <knl keyword="<%=SeoJspHelper.cleanHtml(kwd) %>">
    <%
        out.println(sb.toString());
    %>
  </knl>
</info>
```

Where `StringBuffer` contains the mentioned String . Please suggest how to print it ?

Comment: Hey . If you want to see the output on jsp try <%=sb.toString()%>

Comment: For starters, don't use scriptlets; there are all kinds of problems with them, and this is just one. In fact, if it's possible, it's better to use a templating engine like Thymeleaf instead of JSP.

Comment: just for testing try to use <p> tags , just for sake of playing with it. `<p> <knl keyword="<%=SeoJspHelper.cleanHtml(kwd) %>"> <% out.println(sb.toString()); %> </p>` –  user3624028 1 min ago

Comment: Have You tried to output it <%=sb %> to be sure, sb is not empty?